# Microcopy - Upgrade Once / Lifetime Upgrade / One-time Upgrade

Tags: mobile, user-behavior, user-research, copywriting

I have a **freemium iOS only mobile app** that i'm currently working on.

The app give the user free limited access, and when the user requests access to a `premium` feature, I'm popping the option to upgrade.

When the upgrade screen pops, I'm trying to understand what is the best microcopy to use that will explain(self-explanatory) to the user that **this is a one-time upgrade**. I'm having hard time coming to a conclusion because English is not my native language.

[image]

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Is there room on this screen to give context details. A screen like this would allow you much more too make it clear than trying to fit it all in one button: http://www.appmarketinglab.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/upgrade_page.jpg

Comment: Also interesting to see if 'lifetime' has any legal obligations associated with it

Comment: @Midas I don't believe there is. specially when the users will actually won't pay for any new feature again (+ he has the option the Restore)

Comment: @DasBeasto there is more details above. But I cannot post the entire screen. I've decided to go on the "Lifetime Upgrade", as it just dosent leave the user with questions about the purchase. As well i've reduced the font size by 1 point, to make more margins for each side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run A/B experiments with the following copy:

1. Pay $0.99 once and use forever
2. Lifetime Upgrade for $0.99
3. One time fee of $0.99 for Lifetime use

The second and third options you suggested are a bit confusing. 
'One-time upgrade' may confuse people thinking that I am paying only once now and I may have to pay again.
'Upgrade once for' also doesn't sound right.

Comment: I've decided to go on the "Lifetime Upgrade", as it just dosent leave the user with questions about the purchase. As well i've reduced the font size by 1 point, to make more margins for each side.